# C++ | TCP - receive

Tags: c++, file, sockets, tcp, recv

i need help... i spend much time to write a tcp connection to transfer an image from server to client.

The problem is, that it looks like that the client didnt receive all bytes.

Server output:

```
Anfrage erhalten: img_size...Imagesize sended!
Anfrage erhalten: image...Start
1024 bytes send (1)
2048 bytes send (2)
3072 bytes send (3)
...
```

Client output:

```
Get Imagesize: 75186 bytes
(0) 75186 
(0) (0/75186)
(1) (5/75186)
(2) (80/75186)
.
.
.
(16150/75186)
(16227/75186)
```

at this moment the client wait forever... if number (1) was sended number (1) is received with  5 bytes?!?!?! WWHHHYYY?

Here my Client code:

```
tcp.Send( "image" );
msg = "";

while( msg.length() < size_img ){
    cout << "(" << msg.length() << "/" << size_img << ")" << endl;

    if( msg.length() + 1024 < size_img ){
        g = tcp.receive(1024);
    }else{
        g = tcp.receive(size_img - msg.length());
    }

    ss << msg;
    ss << g;
    msg = ss.str();
    ss.str("");
}

string TCPClient::receive(int size)
{
char buffer[size];
memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));

size_t len = sizeof(buffer);
char *p = buffer;
ssize_t n;

string reply;

while(len > 0 && (n=recv(sock,p,len,0)) > 0){
    p += n;
    len -= (size_t)n;
}
if ( len > 0 || n < 0 ) {
    cout << "receive failed!" << endl;
    return nullptr;
}
//buffer[size-1]='\0';
reply = buffer;
return reply;
}
```

Server Send function:

```
void TCPServer::Send_Bytes(unsigned char* msg, int laenge)
{
for(int i = 0; i < laenge; i=i+1024){
    if(i+1024 < laenge){
        send(newsockfd,msg+i,1024,0);
    }else{
        send(newsockfd,msg+i,laenge - i,0);
        break;
    }
    cout << i << endl;

    usleep(100000);
}

}
```

Please help me... i dont know how to handel that?!?!?

yacobs ;)

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) : "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]." The specific problem is not clear, the code not short and it isn't enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think thats the minimum code u need for interpretation. i hope u see the 2 functions in Client code.
The 2 outputs are no Code!!!

Comment: If the received data contains any `0x00` (zero) bytes then `reply = buffer;` will truncate the data at the 1st zero.

Comment: To make Richard Critten's point as obvious as possible, `std::string` is intended to hold text-format information. Some of the information in binary data, particularly zero bytes, will trigger unwanted behaviour. `std::vector<char>` is a better choice here.

Comment: TCP is a stream. How do you know when one message is done and the next begins? You need to search for a delimiter (or whatever your protocol defines) as you buffer things up, then grab a complete message from the buffer, leaving behind the bytes that have started the next. You cannot simply receive until error or closed connection and copy the whole thing into a string.

Comment: Heyy... thanks for this very helpful answers!!! That 0x00 byte at the ent of std::string was the problem.
I write a void(char* s, int size){...} for receiving the data...and that works very fine!!!
I dindt present all code there, but befor i start my transmission i ask for the image-size so the client know how long he has to wait... ;) are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
void TCPClient::receive_char(char* outStr, int size){
    char buffer[size];
    memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));

    size_t len = sizeof(buffer);
    char *p = buffer;
    ssize_t n;

    while(len > 0 && (n=recv(sock,p,len,0)) > 0){
        p += n;
        len -= (size_t)n;
    }
    if ( len > 0 || n < 0 ) {
        cout << "receive failed!" << endl;
    }
    //buffer[size-1]='\0';
    for(int i=0; i < size; ++i){
        outStr[i] = buffer[i];
    }   
}
```

You can call with:

```
char data[4096];
memset(&data[0], 0, sizeof(data));

tcp.receive_char(data,4096);

for(int i = 0; i < 4096; i++){
    image_bytes[counter] = data[i];
    counter++;
}
```

Maybe there are better solutions... :D